# XBee S2C: Receive data and save to txt-file with Python

Tags: python-2.7, xbee

I try to receive data with an XBee S2C (Coordinator), which is mounted on a Sparkfun USB-explorer. For this I use Python-XBee-Library. API is enabled with escaping. The data were sent by another XBee S2C (Router), which is mounted on an Arduino. To receive the data at the coordinator I use the code:

```
from xbee import XBee
import serial

PORT = 'COM4'
BAUD_RATE = 9600

# Open serial port
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

# Continuously read and print packets
while True:
 try:
  response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
  print response
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  break

ser.close()
```

If I run this code, I will never receive a response although I get the data from the router by XCTU. At one experiment (change in Arduino code) an error message occured at Python:

> *"Unrecognized response packet with id byte {0}".format(data[0]))
>   KeyError: 'Unrecognized response packet with id byte \x90'*

Therefore I have tested some other code with the coordinator:

```
import serial
import time
port = 'COM4'
baudrate = 9600
print 'open ' + port
xbee = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
print 'open file'
d = open("read10.txt",'w')
print 'waiting incoming message...'
while True:
try:
    out = ''
    while xbee.inWaiting() > 0:    
        out += xbee.read(1)

    if out != '':
        print out
        lt = time.localtime()
        # print lt
        messzeit = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", lt)
        print messzeit

        d.write(messzeit + ";" + out)

        for i in range(0,21,1):
           print out[i]
           print hex(ord(out[i]))


    time.sleep(1)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    xbee.close()
    d.close()
    raise
```

With this code I get an ASCII-sequence which fits to the results in XCTU and `hex(ord(out[i])`, but I still wonder, why is wait_read_frame not working and how can I get the correct HEX-results and data of the ASCII-sequence.

ASCII-sequence: `~ � }3� AT��DANI�`

At the router I have written this Arduino-Code first:

`void sendPacket(int temperature, int Filter) {
   // Prepare the Zigbee Transmit Request API packet
  ZBTxRequest txRequest;
    txRequest.setAddress64(0x0000000000000000);`

```
// Grösse des Pakets hängt von den Datentypen ab
AllocBuffer<9> packet;
packet.append<uint8_t>(1);
packet.append<int>(temperature); //Achtung auf Variablenzuweisung
packet.append<int>(Filter);
txRequest.setPayload(packet.head, packet.len());
// send packet
xbee.send(txRequest);
```

`}`

With this code I only see the ASCII-sequence (both XBee are in API-Mode2) `~ }1� }3� AT���   G` idependently from the settings (API/AT and ATAO). 
Afterwards I have written the next code and I have set the coordinator into AT-mode:

`void sendPacket(int temperature, int Filter) {
   // Prepare the Zigbee Transmit Request API packet
  ZBTxRequest txRequest;
    txRequest.setAddress64(0x0000000000000000);`

```
// Grösse des Pakets hängt von den Datentypen ab
uint8_t payload[] = {'D','A','N','I'};
txRequest.setPayload(payload, sizeof(payload));
// send packet
xbee.send(txRequest);
```

`}`

In this case I get `DANI` when executing the Python-Code `out += xbee.read(1)`.

Therefore I would be happy to know, how can I get useful data from my XBee-Coordinator and save it into a txt-file.

Regards and thank you very much
Daniel

Comment: Tilde (0x7E) is the start of frame character sent from an XBee in API mode.  Maybe the XBee module doesn't recognize the frame type of received frames (in your first block of code) and therefore ignores them?  Can you enable any debugging in the "XBee" module to have it dump every frame it parses?

Comment: @tomlogic thank you for your comment. I have done some further tests (see above)

Comment: Check `ATAO` and what value the Python library was written for or expects.  I think changing `ATAO` between 0 and 1 might resolve this situation.

Comment: @tomlogic: Thank your the feedback. I have tried to change [ATAO] from [Native] to [explicit], but there are still the ASCII-lines. I have added some additional info above